# C++ Vector base address shifts

Tags: debugging, vector, stl, stdvector

I recently encounter a bizarre problem with C++/STL vector operations.

Here is how my code looks like. The source code is large, so I just post part of the code.

```
std::vector<Record> Sequence;

...

if(isFound)
{
assert(pos < Sequence.size());
Record ref = Sequence[pos];
ref.Update();  // it's a const function. it does not perform any operation on Sequence
...
Sequence.erase(Sequence.begin() + pos);
Sequence.insert(Sequence.begin(), ref);
}
```

Before the code enters the if block, the data is all correct. However after the ref.Update() operation, the base address of Sequence[0] shifts 1 byte. For example, before the if block, &Sequence[0] = 0x7fffea22eef0. After ref.Update(), it becomes &Sequence[0] = 0x7fffea22eef1. I dumped the data at *0x7fffea22eef0 by gdb, it does not change. The data is still correct and valid, but apparently I cannot read/write the data directly via calling Sequence[0].

I have no idea how to debug this problem now.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Apart from the low level change in adress of the first element of the vector, does it give you an error in any way while accessing Sequence[0]?

Comment: No it doesn't. It throws out an error message and cause the system crash when I try to use a for loop to iterate through all elements in the vector (till it reaches Sequence.size()). The reason is while the base address changes, the result of Sequence.size() also becomes a garbage value.

Comment: Well, I have got the reason. There is an array in ref.Update() and it overflows...which has the value in the array modified.

Comment: You should show more details.